# Delphi slow compiling on Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-2007, windows-10

Somedays ago i have updated from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

I use Delphi 2007 and Delphi XE in a daily basis, and i've noticed that in both IDEs the normal use seems to be a lot slower than it was in Windows 8.1. Compiling a project seems to take more time than it took previously.

I don't know if it could be the cause but i use Windows in a virtual environment with Parallels. But everything in Win 8 seems to be more fluid.

I don't have any anti-virus and Windows Defender is disabled.

I also noticed that when i compile a project, the CPU never goes higher than 40%, so it seems maybe Delphi is not using all available CPU power for some reason.

My machine is a Macbook Pro with 16GB RAM / Core i7 / SSD. The virtual machine has 3GB of RAM because i use the machine only to Delphi, no more programs opened at the same time. Used memory never reaches more than 2GB.

Does anyone noticed this problem ? Anything i could do to improve ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The Delphi compiler is single threaded. Maximum memory usage by IDE/compiler is 2GB. In D2007 you can turn off detailed map generation for faster compilation. So an even faster SSD disk or CPU/RAM are options. I don't know if RAM disks can be used.

Comment: Thanks, where can i turn off detailed map generation ?

Comment: The "Detailed Map File" option is in the Project >Options>Linker page of the IDE. See also [DelphiSpeedUp](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup/).

Comment: Actually is already unchecked. My IDE is already tuned of the DelphiSpeedUp. Maybe i should go back to Windows 8.1... Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: There are some speedup options here: [Delphi: How to organize source code to increase compiler performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/920560/576719)

Comment: I can confirm that something changed from Win 8.1 to 10 ; tested with Win 8 compiling a project and i can see the CPU going to 100% in task manager. The same project compiled in Win 10 never reaches above 40% of CPU. I don't know why, but Delphi seems to use less CPU power in Windows 10 and the compiling takes a lot more time.

Comment: It seems to be something related to Windows 10, not Delphi. I did some tests with other applications and the CPU usage never goes above 40 or 50%.

Comment: You are running inside a VM right?

Comment: Extending upon David's comment, a virtual machine can never guarantee CPU usage. Not only does the host OS have a lot to do with how much CPU its guest OS can use, but also any VM has a strict control over CPU usage and is subject to any amount of limitation depending on the OS within the VM.

Comment: Yes, i'm using inside a VM, but both machines are running inside a VM. The Windows 8.1 runs a lot faster then the Win 10 one.

Comment: Well, almost 1-year later i could not make Delphi work in W10 as fast as it was on W8. So i'm still sticking with W8.

Comment: Enabling or disabling HyperThreading in the bios can make a diffrence on this as well.