# How to detect useless Delphi units in the interface and implementation uses clauses?

Tags: delphi, refactoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I identify and get rid of unused units in the “uses clause” in Delphi 7 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881778/how-can-i-identify-and-get-rid-of-unused-units-in-the-uses-clause-in-delphi-7)

Is there a wizard/tool to automatically detect all useless units?

If in the current unit I "use classes" but in practice I don't need it I can of course manually remove Classes. But how can I do this automatically for all units in a project? Is there a way different than "delete one, try to compile, if succesful save"?

Of course often what happens is that you drop a component on the form, some units are added, you delete the component and the units are not removed.

Or I refactor code, I move some classes in another unit.

Comment: What about units with initialization code? Are they too useless?

Comment: http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en takes care also of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Icarus - Uses List Analyzer for Delphi](http://www.peganza.com/#ICARUS)