# is there a tool to check unused uses in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I identify and get rid of unused units in the “uses clause” in Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881778/how-can-i-identify-and-get-rid-of-unused-units-in-the-uses-clause-in-delphi-7)

is there a too that can check for unneeded uses units, that expand the project beyond its needs?

example we have

```
unit a; 

uses b,c;

procedure aP;
var bI:Tb;
begin
  bI := Tb.create;
  bI.free;
end;

end.
```

where there is no use of c.
c was introduced to the project, and never being used at the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the tool in [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) or the one in [Peganza](http://www.peganza.com/).

Beware that even if you do not refer to a symbol defined in a unit, the inclusion of that unit can have an impact on your project. Including a unit means that code in any `initialization` or `finalization` sections runs and that can, of course, change the meaning of your program. The canonical example of this is a replacement memory manager.

The [FAQ for GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/faq.html#uses) discusses this issue and explains why they do not offer such a facility.

Comment: cnWizards by default will not un-use units which have initialization or finalization, this can be changed in the wizard dialog

Comment: OMG cnPack is legendary!!! thanks :D